# How to show the second page records on page load using jpages library

Tags: jquery, pagination

I am using jPages pagination library for pagination in my rails application. I have set to show 10 records per page.How can I show the second page records on page load.
Here the configuration for jPages:

```
$(function(){
    $("div.holder").jPages({
        containerID : "ReviewContainer",
        previous : "",
        next : "",
        perPage : 4,
        delay : 20,
        callback: function (pages, items) {
            if (items.count > 4) {
                $("div.holder").show();
            } else {
                $("div.holder").hide();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I have some records on my home page where I used the pagination. And if click on any record it will redirect to its details page where I used the same pagination configuration. But if I clicked on the 12th record from home page then on the detail page it will show 10 records only. How can I configure it to show the selected record on detail page as well.

Comment: Please take the time to format your question correctly. It was almost unreadable before.

Comment: The callback is used  to hide the holder div if length is less than required records for pagination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an attribute called `startPage` make use of that

```
  $(function () {
      /* initiate the plugin */
      $("div.holder").jPages({
          containerID: "itemContainer",
          perPage: 10,
          startPage: 1,
          startRange: 1,
          midRange: 5,
          endRange: 1
      });
  });
```

Refer JS portion of [this](http://luis-almeida.github.io/jPages/pagination.html)

Answer (score 0):

**Jpages** has `jump to page` feature using which you can go to particular page.

on window load you can

```
$(function(){

   /* when button is clicked */
   $("button").click(function(){
  /* get given page */
    var page = parseInt( $("input").val() );

    /* jump to that page */
    $("div.holder").jPages( page );

});
}
```

follow below link:
http://luis-almeida.github.io/jPages/jumptopage.html